# Default action variable for start_form

Tags: html, perl

I'm currently in the process of writing my own web server to handle cgi scripts. In my current test perl script, I have this little bit of code

```
print start_html("CGI Test Page"),
   h1("CGI Test Page"),
   h2("Post Test:"),
   start_form(-method=>"POST",),
   "Post Value: ",textfield('postKey'),
   submit("Submit Post"),
   end_form;
```

which as you can see, start_html has no action parameter assigned in the form definition. But with this code, I get the following html output for that form definition:

```
<form method="post" action="/cgitest.cgi%" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I'm getting that odd character appended to the end of the action variable. So my question is this: Since I don't define the action value in the perl script, which environment variable is it using to define its action?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce with your code.  That should mean it is something else in your configuration, not in this part of your code.

Comment: @Afresh1 Oh I already know it's something in my configuration. I'm not running Apache or anything, I'm running a personally built server. There's really no way to reproduce it on your end without me giving you the entire server code. Thus, if I know what this method uses as a default action value, I can isolate the problem to a certain environment variable I'm sending to the cgi script. My intuition tells me that it uses the REQUEST_URI environment variable, but if I do a printf of that variable before it gets sent, it does not have the character tacked on to the end like it does in the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the relevant part from the [CGI.pm source](https://metacpan.org/source/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.55/lib/CGI.pm#L1967):

```
if (defined $action) {
   $action = $self->_maybe_escapeHTML($action);
}
else {
   $action = $self->_maybe_escapeHTML($self->request_uri || $self->self_url);
}
```

As you had guessed, if you don't define the action, it attempts to use `$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'}`, but if that's empty, it uses the URL of the script.  The subroutines that define that URL are [`self_url`](https://metacpan.org/source/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.55/lib/CGI.pm#L2824) and [`url`](https://metacpan.org/source/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.55/lib/CGI.pm#L2845), so hopefully the source code there will help you determine where in your configuration that extra percent sign is coming from.